# How to debug when the index size is too large in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Im indexing only 1000 documents and the index shows a size 0f 300MB. This doesnt look normal. How can I debug this behavior and check if something is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The weight of an index is not only made of the document bytes, but also the deleted documents, which are all the old versions of the documents + all the ones that have been deleted. Every time your re-index a document with the same ID, the old version that was previously stored goes to the deleted segments, and as a result, the size of your index grows.

You can try to [optimize](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-optimize.html) your index with `max_num_segments=1`

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/_optimize?max_num_segments=1'
```

**UPDATE**

Note that as of ES 2.1, the Optimize API has been deprecated and renamed to [Force Merge API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html)

Answer (score 2):

I feel you might have some large documents or malformed documents with lots of data that your code added by bug. This has happened to me. What i did was to enable size parameter in the mapping and then i did a sort based on size to see which document has the highest size.

Size mapping - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-size-field.html

Once this is done , just so a sort like below -

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_size": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does mapping the size consume space? Thanks!